# Get message for all images uploaded instead of for each one

Tags: jquery, ajax, perl

I send some images to a Perl script via an AJAX request

```
$("form#multiupload").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url:   "/cgi-bin/upload_my_images.pl",
        type:        'POST',
        async:       false,
        cache:       false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data:        formData,
        success:     function (data) {
            alert(data)
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

I am uploading the images to the server with Perl

```
my @fh = $cgi->param("img");

foreach my $fh (@fh) {

    my $uploaddir = 'somedir';
    my $serverFile = $uploaddir . "/" . ( split( /[\\\/]/, $filename ) )[-1];
    my $buffer;

    open( FILE, ">$serverFile" ) or die $!;
    binmode FILE;
    binmode $fh;

    while ( my $bytesread = read( $fh, $buffer, 1024 ) ) {
        print FILE $buffer;
    }

    close(FILE);
}
```

When the upload is successful I get the alert message.

Is it possible to get a message when all images have uploaded successfully, or must I upload every single image with its own AJAX request?

Comment: What is the action on the browser to initiate this? How would you select the images to be uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly (and most importantly) *get rid of `async: false`*. It's horrendous practice to use it as it blocks the UI thread. If you check the console you'll event see the browser warning you not to use it.

Secondly, if you want individual messages about each file being uploaded then you would need to send them separately as the `progress` event only works for the request as a whole.

You could do it the old-fashioned way and send a single request to do the upload, and then send other requests every ~1sec to monitor its progress and check what file uploads have completed, but this would put extra load on your server and is, frankly, an ugly bodge.

Comment: *"It's horrendous practice to use it as it blocks the UI thread"* I think *horrendous* is hugely overstating it. (Wouldn't *bad* do fine?) It rather spoils much of the point of AJAX, but it's no worse than non-AJAX code and at least the client screen is still not refreshed

Comment: Personal opinion really, but I believe it's worse than non-AJAX code. The whole point of AJAX is that it's asynchronous. Making it run synchronously makes the point of the request entirely redundant and also makes the browser look as though it has hung while the request awaits a response. This is why `async: false` is being deprecated, and why browsers show warnings in the console when you use it. It's just plain bad practice in the vast majority of cases. If you're going to do AJAX, do it right and use callbacks.

Comment: I don't disagree except that it *can't* be worse than non-AJAX code, which also *"makes the browser look as though it has hung"*. I wouldn't want this in production code though

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way:

1. I create an session id and send the form via ajax to the server.
2. The perl script upload every single image and do some process withit. Subsequently the script writes into an logfile (named by the sesseion id) the status of the process. After the last loop, an finish flag will be written to the log.
3. On the client-side, i check with jquery .get() every 2 seconds the content of the logfile and write it into DOM. If the finish flag is set, the process will be canceled and a signal will be send to the server to delete the logfile.

Perhaps not the best way but it works fine...